# How to disable Apache caching in Apache-XAMPP?

Tags: php, apache, caching, xampp

I am having this weird problem with my XAMPP-Apache.
I am making an log-in system where form is posted to redirect.php page.
I updated the redirect.php and but still it is showing me the same old result.
There is not even a single line to redirect(header fn call) it to another page but still it redirects to home.php page as it was doing in older script.
I tried clearing cache of my browser and changing the browser for testing but didn't work...I even tried rebooting the server but no change.
Please help me through....

Comment: PHP scripts are not cached by default - there is probably some other problem with your code

Comment: When I was trying caching on localhost, I accidentally keep he op_cache.dll in the php.ini. I just comment out this line and it works same as before ```;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll```.

Answer (score 18):

Tried this? Should work in both `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` and in a VirtualHost (usually placed in httpd-vhosts.conf if you have included it from your httpd.conf)

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

> 100% Prevent Files from being cached
>
> This is similar to how google ads employ the header Cache-Control:
>   private, x-gzip-ok="" > to prevent caching of ads by proxies and
>   clients. From
>   http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html

And optionally add the extension for the template files you are retrieving if you are using an extension other than .html for those.

Comment: @cascading-style Kindly accept the answer. I need the bounty ;)

Answer (score 3):

If request is identical, it's possible that you receiving response from cache.

### Solution 1:

You can try to have every time unique request by adding for example time stamp.

### Solution 2 (not every server will accept - depend on server setting):

You can set header params to your request like:

```
'If-Modified-Since' = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'
'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache'
'Pragma' = 'no-cache'
```

### Solution 3:

Play with server config :)

Answer (score 0):

comment this part in httpd.conf:

LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so

Comment: @Micha answering your question: in the file /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf look for the line "LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so" and add a # in the beginning of the line. save the file and restart the apache server.

Comment: I had also to comment the line "cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so" because apache was complaining about it in the log, refusing to start.