# Changes to code won't display from potential cache issue

Tags: php, apache, mamp

There's an issue I'm experiencing that seems related to caching, but I'm not 100% positive.

I'm working with MAMP to render PHP inside of HTML. When I write some lines of code and go to the appropriate page, my code is manifest. However, if I make small changes to the code, I'm not able to get it to change with a refresh.

More than that, I'm finding that hard refreshes with and without cache clearing aren't solving the issue as well.

Here's a concrete example. Within PHP I declare a couple of numerical variables. I then set an `if` statement so that if the second variable is higher than the first, text is displayed on the page. When I change the value of the variables so the opposite would be true, the text continues to show on the page, even though the `if` statement is false.

I refresh, hard refresh, clear the cache, and even close the browser window. It often takes several combinations of these to finally register my change.

I thought the issue might have been with MAMP and so I tried it with XAMPP, but the results were the same. This makes sense, as they both use an Apache server (provided the issue is server related).

This is becoming very bothersome and I'm not sure where the issue lies. Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848055/how-to-disable-apache-caching-in-apache-xampp . Have you enabled the OpCache extension?

Comment: This proved useful, thanks!